# Display scroll bar for longer

Tags: macos

I'm one of these people who likes to grab the scroll bar and move it around now-n-then when I'm not using the scroll wheel on my mouse.

But what I find really annoying is I have to scroll to get it to appear, which is fine, but it disappears before I can grab it.

How can I increase the duration that the scroll bar shows before it disappears?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run

```
defaults write -g NSOverlayScrollerHideDelay -float 3
```

where `3` is a value in seconds and quit and reopen applications to apply the changes.

I found the preference key by running `mdfind kMDItemContentType=public.unix-executable -onlyin /System|xargs strings 2>/dev/null|grep -E '^[[:alnum:].-]{10,80}$'|grep -i scroll`.

Comment: Worked perfectly. I set it to 5 seconds :D

Answer (score 0):

One other option is to set up the behaver via one of the three options in "System Preferences=>General":

[image]